# C# - StreamReader SecurityException Process OpenFileDialog related Errors on WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, streamreader, openfiledialog

Hey Everyone, Background: 
I'm developing a WinForms application using C# with an OpenFileDialog, FileBrowserDialog that will convert multiple files from excel to 1 csv file using a command line executable.

Errors: What using directives or assembly references should I add to prevent these errors??

- '**sOut**' does not exist in the current context
- '**sErr**' does not exist in the current context
- '**sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedFiles**' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedFiles' and no extension method accepting a first arg of type system.windows.forms.openfiledialog could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
- '**sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedPath**' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedPath' and no extension method accepting a first arg of type system.windows.forms.openfiledialog could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
- '**SecurityException**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
- '**Process**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
- '**fileName**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
- '**sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames**' cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

Thanks!

Here's the code from the MainForm.CS file:

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Security;

    // Select Source Files Button 
    private void sourceFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "i:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\Review\\";
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;)|*.xls;*.xlsx;|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.Title = "Excel File Browser";

        DialogResult dr = this.sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string consolidatedFolder = targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath; 
            // Read the files
            foreach (String file in sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Copy each selected xlsx files into the specified TargetFolder 

                    System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, consolidatedFolder + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)); 

                    // Convert each selected XLSX File to CSV Using the command prompt
                    // [I:\CommissisionReconciliation\App\ConvertExcel\ConvertExcelTo.exe ^ .XLS file location ^ filename.csv] 
                    // example: ConvertExcelTo.exe ^ I:\CommissisionReconciliation\ Review\_Consolidated\ALH\2011-350-00-600070-
                    // 03-09alh-AMLHS of Florida.xlsx ^ 2011-350-00-600070-03-09alh-AMLHS of Florida.csv

                    Process convertFilesProcess = new Process();

                    // command prompt execution 
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "I:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\App\\ConvertExcel\\";
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ConvertExcelTo.exe";
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " ^ " + targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "^" + csvFileName + ".csv";
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    convertFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    convertFilesProcess.Start();

                    StreamReader sOut = convertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
                    StreamReader sErr = convertFilesProcess.StandardError;

                }

                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                    MessageBox.Show("Security error. The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                    "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                     + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                     "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    Stream sOut
                    .Close();
                    sErr.Close();
                }

                try
                {
                    // Combine all .csv files into 1 csv file using the command prompt
                    // [.csv File location: Copy *.csv ^ filename.csv]
                    // example: [.CSV I:\CommissisionReconciliation\ Review\_Consolidated\ALH\: Copy *.csv 
                    // ^2011-350-00-600070-03-09alh-AMLHS of Florida.csv)

                    Process consolidateFilesProcess = new Process();

                    // substring function to take off the extension from sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName
                    // int csvFileName.Length = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName.Length - 3;  

                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "I:\\CommissisionReconciliation\\App\\ConvertExcel\\";
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ConvertExcelTo.exe"; 
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " .CSV " + " ^ " + targetFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + ": Copy *.csv ^" + csvFileName+ ".csv";
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    consolidateFilesProcess.Start();

                    StreamReader sOut = consolidateFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
                    StreamReader sErr = consolidateFilesProcess.StandardError;
                }

                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                    MessageBox.Show("Security error. The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                    "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                     + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                     "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    sOut.Close();
                    sErr.Close();
                }

            } // ends foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        }  // ends if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)


        if (sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Log("Source Files: " + sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedFiles);
        }
        textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedFiles;
    } // ends selectFilesButton_Click method 


    // Source Folder Path Click Button
```

Comment: Fixed Error: '**Process**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) w/ using System.Diagnostics;

Comment: Fixed Error: 'SecurityException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) w/ using System.Security;

Comment: Fixed Error: 'fileName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) by changing to sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName

Comment: We'll give you another hour or so.

Comment: come on, hans solo, i dont want to spend hours debugging lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the following Errors so far:

- '**SecurityException**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) by adding

  ```
    using System.Security;
  ```
- '**Process**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) by adding:

  ```
    using System.Diagnostics;
  ```
- '**fileName**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) by changing to sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName

  ```
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName, consolidatedFolder + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName));
  ```
- '**sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames**' cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string' by changing to sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName

  ```
    textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName;
  ```
- '**sOut**' & '**sErr**' does not exist in the current context fixed by changing placement of the close statements as follows. I'm not sure if this messes up the exception catcher or not but we will see:

  ```
    StreamReader sOut = consolidateFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
    StreamReader sErr = consolidateFilesProcess.StandardError;
    sOut.Close();
    sErr.Close();
  ```
- '**sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedFiles**' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedFiles' and no extension method accepting a first arg of type system.windows.forms.openfiledialog could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?). Fixed by changing SelectedFiles to FileNames:

  ```
    // Text box value declarataions
    private void textBoxSourceFiles_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName = textBoxSourceFiles.Text;
    }
  ```

'sourceFileOpenFileDialog.SelectedPath' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedPath' and no extension method accepting a first arg of type system.windows.forms.openfiledialog could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?). Fixed by changing SelectedPath to FileName:

```
        if (sourceFileOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your error

**sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileNames** cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

You need to change up this section, you're trying to push a string array into a string (.Text)

```
using (myStream)
{
   // change FileNames to FileName
   textBoxSourceFiles.Text = sourceFileOpenFileDialog.FileName; 

}
```

Maybe iterate through the FileNames array and concatenate the strings together to put into .Text?

For the issues with ".SelectedFiles" and ".SelectedPath", those are not properties of an openFileDialog, so thats why it is complaining..

Again you can use ".FileNames" to get at the files that were selected in the dialog(or ".FileName" if you are allowing only one selection)

With **sOut** and **sErr** you are setting them up late in your process and cleaning them up in your finally statement, what may be happening is if the process bombs before you get to your

```
StreamReader sOut = covertFilesProcess.StandardOutput;
StreamReader sErr = covertFilesProcess.StandardError;
```

lines then when you hit the finally, it doesn't know what **sOut** and **sErr** to close are, since they were never made yet.

Comment: thanks for your response! Can you edit your answer to include the correct code? What are the correct properties that I should use to reference path and files selected in the openFileDialog? how would you fix the sOut process in the code....

Comment: Should i use this string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath); ?